# Showing that a CW complex is compactly generated

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Let $X$ be a CW complex. I need to show that $X$ is finitely generated, which means that it's topology is coherent with its compact subspaces.

A space $X$ is said to be compactly generated if:

A subspace $A$ is closed in $X$ if and only if $A ∩ K$ is closed in $K$ for all compact subspaces $K ⊆ X$.

So i'm having trouble getting started here. I suspect that the topology of a CW complex is very connected to the characteristic maps for each open cell. Before we get going here, I have a question: Is an open cell of a CW complex necessarily open in the topology of the CW complex? I want to say it is, because it is homeomorphic to the interior of a disk, but somebody told me it wasn't. Can somebody offer some insight here? Thanks!

Comment: Open cell is almost never open in the entire CW complex. This is especially true when the dimension of the cell is lower then the dimension of the space. For example in a closed disk $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ you can pick a CW structure such that the arch without a poll $S^1\backslash\{x\}$ is an open cell which clearly is not open in $D$.

Comment: And the main statement follows from the fact that every compact subspace of a CW comples is fully contained in a finite subcomplex and because a finite complex is compact (hence compactly generated).

Comment: What definition are you using for the CW complex topology? This should fall almost immediately from the definition.